# Inconsistent focus() with React in Safari/Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, safari

I recently ran into an issue in React when cross-browser testing. The issue occurs when calling `focus()` on an element containing React's auto-generated `<span>` tags.

**Simplified Component**

My component, a `<Button/>`, is an abstraction of a normal `<button>` with additional features. Here's a simplified version:

The output of:

```
<Button value="Button"/>
```

is:

```
<button><span>Button</span></button>
```

Due to React's auto-wrapping of floating text nodes in a span so it can assign a `data-reactid`, the text within the `<button>` is wrapped in `<span>` tags.

The button has an `onClick()` method to call `event.target.focus()` on the element.

**The Issue**

In Chrome/Firefox clicking the button sets focus on the button. In Safari, clicking the button does not always set focus on the button. Instead the `<body>` receives focus.

After several hours of fiddling I discovered the button receives focus only when clicked outside of React's auto-generated `<span>` tags (the blue areas of the button below). Clicking within the `<span>` tags created by React (the black areas of the button below) will cause the `<body>` to gain focus.

[image]

Again, this only happens in Safari.

In Chrome/Firefox, clicking either of the areas results in the `<button>` gaining focus.

Here's a [CodePen](http://s.codepen.io/brettdewoody/debug/RaYeJp) containing the full example, the steps to reproduce:

1. Open [the CodePen](http://s.codepen.io/brettdewoody/debug/RaYeJp) in Safari.
2. Open your console.
3. Click the button, within the dark area (corresponding to the `<span>` tag). You'll notice the `focused` element (using `document.activeElement`) is most likely the `<body>`.
4. Click the button, within the blue area (corresponding to the `<button>` tag. You'll notice the `focused` element is the `<button>`.

**Question**

Is there a preferred method for making the behavior consistent across browsers? Or is this unrelated to React and merely a difference in how Safari/Chrome/Firefox handle `focus()`?

One possible solution: set `pointer-events: none;` on the inner `<span>` element. This would allow clicks on the `<span>` to propagate through to the `<button>`. This seems hackish however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just use a ref?

aka

```
something(event){
    this.refs.button.focus()
}
render(){
    // stuff
    return (
        <button ref="button" onClick={this.something}>
            {some text here that will make a span element around it}
        </button>
    );
}
```

[sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghn923sb/1/)

Comment: That fixes part of the problem - clicking the `<span>` causes the `<button>` to gain focus. However, if I click the `<button>` then move over the `<span>` it causes some CSS wonkiness. I'll need to leave the `pointer-events: none` unfortunately.  However, this does fix the issue.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody can you define CSS wonkiness? is there something you are trying to do with css on the button?

Comment: I have a few color/transition changes for various states defined in the CSS. It looks like the `onMouseOut()` method fires when moving from the `<button>` to the `<span>` and vice versa, in Safari only.

Comment: Ok so all you need to do is with whatever class or style you are applying do it for the span also in css.

Comment: The issue is when moving from the `<button>` to `<span>` the `<button>` loses focus and causes CSS issues. Do you think it's a React issue, or a Safari issue?

Comment: not following. I dont know what the style is and I dont know what you are doing so its really hard to help. it sounds like a browser issue. are you using javascript to assign styles? or css through a classname?

Comment: I've changed the colors on the Codepen to make it more obvious - http://s.codepen.io/brettdewoody/debug/RaYeJp. Clicking the black `<span>` (in Safari) won't set the focus on the button. And clicking the blue `<button>` and then moving into the black `<span>` will cause the button to lose focus.

Comment: i still have no idea what these colors are supposed to be. I need to see code. you are probably just not accounting for the span when changing colors

Comment: Ah, I thought you could get to it through the link - http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/RaYeJp

Comment: The black color is only there for presentation, so you can see where the `<span>` is.

Comment: clicking the black span in safari works for me when I use the ref focus

Comment: why dont you just do a mouse over?